# SSL for Apache2 Ubuntu Wordpress PLEASE HELP i need direction

Tags: apache2, ssl, wordpress, certificates

Hi i have ubuntu as a webserver and have loaded wordpress on there already.

However when implementing SSL (bought from godaddy), the https only works for the homepage `https://www.myexample.com` but not the other links to the site such as "about us" `https://www.myexample.com/about-us` it gives :

```
404 NOT FOUND

The requested URL /about-us/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.myexample.com Port 443
```

I'm not sure what im doing wrong ?

I have already tried a few things in the `default-ssl.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably way too late, but I experienced the exact same issue when trying to install my self signed SSL certificate on my virtual host tonight.

I followed the instructions provided by [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04) and it worked very well. But I would get a `404` every time I was trying to navigate to the about-us page, or any other page.

I fixed the issue by adding the following block in my `default-ssl` file  (basically I added the block to the code displayed in "Step Three" in the above article) and then of course `sudo service apache2 restart`.

You should be careful with `Order allow,deny` as this could raise security concerns. I have `allow from all` to suit my needs, but you might want something different.

```
    <Directory /var/www/YOURDIRECTORYNAME/>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```